# Create a Linq Tree -> Any method Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm trying to write manually this linq sentence:

```
IEnumerable<C> classes = this.cs
    .Where(c => c.Properties.Any(p => 
        p.Key.Equals("key1") &&
        p.Value.Equals("v1")
    )
);
```

As you can see I'm calling to `Any` extension method on a `c.Properties` property of `C` class.

Then, inside `Any` method I've written an `And` with two `Equals`.

I need to create this sentence using `Expression` builders.
Up to now, I've been able to write this:

```
Type entityType = typeof(T);
PropertyInfo collectionPropertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty("Properties");
if (collectionPropertyInfo == null)
    throw new ArgumentException(
        string.Format(
            "{0} collection doesn't appear in {1}",
            "Properties",
            entityType.Name
        )
    );

Type collGenericType = collectionPropertyInfo
    .GetType()
    .GetGenericArguments()
    .FirstOrDefault();

MemberExpression collectionMemberExpression = Expression.Property(
    Expression.Parameter(entityType),
    collectionPropertyInfo
);

MethodInfo anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods()
    .Where(m => 
        m.Name.Equals("Any") && 
       m.GetParameters().Length == 2
    )
    .Single()
    .MakeGenericMethod(collGenericType);

BinaryExpression innerConditionExpression = Expression.AndAlso(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(collGenericType, "p"), "Key"),
        Expression.Constant("key1")
    ),
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(collGenericType, "p"), "Value"),
        Expression.Constant("v1")
    )
);
```

I don't know how to write `Call to Any method` where instance is `collectionMemberExpression` and iiner condition is `innerConditionExpression`.

Comment: Use the [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343914(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: What is the type of `Properties`? What is the T type?

Comment: Please note that `Enumerable.Any` takes in a `Func`, not an `Expression`.

Comment: This means that you have to compile `innerConditionExpression` and pass it in as a constant to `Enumerable.Any`. It is hard to work with your current code because it is not complete. It would be easier to help if you provide code that we can run.